# Can't get basic select2 multiselect to function in my browser, using Laravel 5.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm trying to incorporate select2 multi-select functionality in my application but can't seem to get it to work. I have included my code below. I have run through all of the basic issues that people usually face and my code should be loading in appropriate order.

**View**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@extends('layouts.navbar')

@section('content')

                <fieldset>
                        <small class="errorMessage"></small>
                        <label for="tags">Tags</label>
                        <select name="tags" id="tagsList" class="select2-multi form-control" multiple="multiple">
                            @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                 <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                </fieldset>
```

**Layout file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/select2.min.css')}}">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=ZCOOL+XiaoWei" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>


<title>Plant Lab</title>
</head>
<body>

@include('includes.messages')
@yield('jumbotron')
@yield('content')



<script src="{{asset('js/custom.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('js/select2.min.js')}}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Custom JS file**

```
// Select 2 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.jselect2-multi').select2();
});
```

My browser is just rendering a regular HTML select form and the Select2 is not being applied. Where am I going wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your input field name array,

```
<select name="tags[]" id="tagsList" class="select2-multi form-control" multiple="multiple">
  @foreach($tags as $tag)
  <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

You make a type mistake,

```
// Select 2 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.select2-multi').select2(); // class name should be select2-multi not jselect2-multi
});
```

Comment: @carlstrom96, if you think this answer useful give a upvote.